# T-SQL - Stuff to CSV for only certain groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, csv

Example Data:

```
ID Name   Role
1  Jack   Manager
2  John   Manager
3  James  Employee
4  Helen  Employee
5  Tony   Manager
6  Louise Employee
```

How could I return:

```
Name               Role
Jack, John, Louise Manager
James              Employee
Helen              Employee
Louise             Employee
```

I think I only need to use STUFF with XML on a specific group. Please advise.

Then I need to manipulate further to:

```
Name   ListOfManagers     Role
NULL   Jack, John, Louise Manager
James  NULL               Employee
Helen  NULL               Employee
Louise NULL               Employee
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XML PATH` like `Role` specific filter.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7cce/1)**

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(6), [Role] varchar(8));

INSERT INTO Employee
    ([ID], [Name], [Role])
VALUES
    (1, 'Jack', 'Manager'),
    (2, 'John', 'Manager'),
    (3, 'James', 'Employee'),
    (4, 'Helen', 'Employee'),
    (5, 'Tony', 'Manager'),
    (6, 'Louise', 'Employee');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((
SELECT ',' + Name 
FROM Employee E2
WHERE (E1.Role = 'Manager' OR E1.ID = E2.ID)
ORDER BY ID ASC
FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') as Name,Role
FROM Employee E1
```

**Output**

```
Name    Role
Helen   Employee
Jack,John,James,Helen,Tony,Louise   Manager
James   Employee
Louise  Employee
```

You can even optionally `UNION` 2 different sets of One for managers with `GROUP BY` and one for Employee and use XML Path in only Managers query.

**EDIT**

Based on the updated question you can use `UNION ALL` like this..

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7cce/2)**

**Query**

```
SELECT
NULL as Name,
STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + Name 
    FROM Employee E2
    WHERE E2.Role = E1.Role
    ORDER BY ID ASC
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') as ListofManagers,
Role
FROM Employee E1
WHERE Role = 'Manager'
GROUP BY Role

UNION ALL 

SELECT Name,NULL,Role
FROM Employee
WHERE Role = 'Employee'
```

**Output**

```
|   Name | ListofManagers |     Role |
|--------|----------------|----------|
| (null) | Jack,John,Tony |  Manager |
|  James |         (null) | Employee |
|  Helen |         (null) | Employee |
| Louise |         (null) | Employee |
```

Comment: wow thank you! I will use a case statement to complete my question amendment. Regarding the union suggestion I had considered it, but I think the original solution is neater.

Comment: yup, just add respective `CASE` and you're good to go. In your updated scenario the `UNION ALL` Query should suit you better.